# Why VS Compiler doesn't auto init local variables on C++?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012

Whenever I declare a new variable, like the bellow struct, I have to init it with 0's. So, my question is, there is any possible scenario which I'll not want my variable be initialized?

```
MY_STRUCT msVar1; //May have some trash data from old stack values.
MY_STRUCT msVar2 = {}; //Will have only 0's, which is a "clean" variable.
```

I tried to think in many possibles scenarios where I would need my variable to don't be initialized as 0, but I wasn't able...

What I mean is, isn't better if I don't set any value at initialization, it automatically fill it with 0's?

```
MY_STRUCT msVar1; //If I don't set any initialization value, auto fill it with 0's
MY_STRUCT msVar2 = {10, 20}; //Now I've specified a initialization value, so doesn't need to auto fill.
```

Actually I'm using Visual Studio 2012 and if I don't init my struct with `{}`, it'll contains many "trash" data.

Comment: There may be situations where you don't use the variables until you set them to specific values at a later stage, and you have no use for zero-initialization. So you don't have to incur the overhead of an initialization that you don't need. C++ has a general philosophy of not giving you anything you don't ask for.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why aren't pointers initialized with NULL by default?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1910832/why-arent-pointers-initialized-with-null-by-default)

Comment: @juanchopanza: Other than headaches when trying to parse C++11's syntax in older compilers / brains. I never asked for that, and C++ gives it to me.

Comment: @LokiAstari Those questions are similar, but that didnt answered what I've asked. Anyway, thanks for pointing this question, it was helpfull also.

Comment: @AfonsoLage: I have to disagree. Though one is talking about pointers the other about structures the reason for not initializing variables is exactly the same.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not just Visual Studio. The language C++ specifies that variables (with some exceptions) are not initialized, so they will contain garbage until either initialized or assigned.

It should be possible to write very high-performance code in C++, and to mandate that the compiler must add extra code, that is not always needed, could slow down some of those programs.

Comment: Despite the question's title, the real question might be "why is this so?"

Comment: @juanchopanza: I was to fast with the Post button. I've added an explanation. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Because the C++ standard says that accessing an uninitialized value causes undefined behavior. If the compiler emitted code to zero out the structure, people writing performance sensitive code would be unhappy.