# value by default for a pointer in a structure in C++

Tags: c++, pointers, struct

I have a `struct` named `Node` which has 2 attributes: an `int v` and another `Node*` named `child`. If I do not explicitly provide a constructor for my `struct`, what value does `child` receive by default?

```
struct Node   
{
    int v;
    Node * child; 
};
```

It seems that it is not the `NULL` pointer, so I had to write a constructor inside my structure

```
struct Node   
{
    int v;
    Node * child; 
    // constructor
    Node():v(0),child(NULL){}
};
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why aren't pointers initialized with NULL by default?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1910832/why-arent-pointers-initialized-with-null-by-default)

Answer (score 4):

It will be uninitialised. Reading from it before setting its value in the constructor initialiser list, or the constructor body, is undefined behaviour.

Note that there are two exceptions: variables with `static` storage duration, and objects created with `new Node()` (as opposed to `new Node`). In both those cases, the object will be zero-initialised.

Answer (score 0):

The initial value of `child` pointer in this case will depend on *external* factors determined at the point of object definition: storage duration of `Node` object and initializer (if any).

- If you declare a `Node` object with static storage duration, the pointer will be zero-initialized.

  ```
  Node n1; // `n1.child` is null pointer

  void foo()
  {
    static Node n2; // `n2.child` is null pointer
  }
  ```
- If you declare a `Node` object with automatic storage duration and an initializer, the pointer will initialized as directed by the initializer

  ```
  void foo()
  {
    Node n3{}; // `n3.child` is null pointer
    Node n4 = { 42 }; // `n4.child` is null pointer
  }
  ```
- If you declare a `Node` object with automatic storage duration and no initializer, the pointer will not be initialized at all

  ```
  void foo()
  {
    Node n5; // `n5.child` is garbage value
  }
  ```
- If you allocate a `Node` object dynamically with an initializer, the pointer will initialized as directed by the initializer

  ```
  Node *n6 = new Node(); // `n6->child` is null pointer
  Node *n7 = new Node{}; // `n7->child` is null pointer
  Node *n8 = new Node{ 42 }; // `n8->child` is null pointer
  ```
- If you allocate a `Node` object dynamically without an initializer, the pointer will not be initialized at all

  ```
  Node *n9 = new Node;   // `n9->child` is garbage value
  ```
- If you declare `Node` as a subobject of a bigger object, the initialization rules propagate from bigger object to `Node` subobject.

If you want your class members to be zero-initialized in all cases, you can explicitly write a constructor or use C++11 member initializer syntax

```
struct Node   
{
    int v = 0;
    Node *child = nullptr; 
};
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Actually I wrote in my code Node * foo = new Node; so Child was not initialized. Thanks for the idea of nullptr from C++11 :-)