# Pointers Default initialized Value is not NULL?

Tags: c++, pointers, null-pointer

How do we know pointers are not initialized to NULL by default?
There is a similar questions directed at [Why aren't pointers initialized with NULL by default?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1910832/why-arent-pointers-initialized-with-null-by-default)
Just for checking, here is a very simple code just to see if a pointer is set to NULL by default.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int* x;
    if(!x)
        cout << "nullptr" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

and at the output, I received nullptr message. I appreciate if someone can clarify this.

Comment: If these were local variables it is undefined behavior. If they are static or global variables it is expected. Either way raw pointers should be used sparingly in modern `c++`

Comment: There's nothing that says that an unitialized pointer cannot be null. There's nothing it the standard that says that it _will_ be null either (in general).

Comment: In some contexts pointers do get initialized to `nullptr`. Right now is too generic to give an answer.

Comment: @Mat without code, it is impossible to say. There are cases when standard guarantees a pointer will be `nullptr`.

Comment: you cannot tell the difference between a value 0 due to initialization and a 0 due to no-initialization. In general its not a good idea to check the rules of c++ by trial and error. If some thing is undefined then you can get any outcome (typically just the one you expect until you make a demo for your boss)

Comment: Here is an initialized pointer to null:  `char* p1 = nullptr;`   And here is an uninitialized pointer:  `char * p2;`

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2218254/variable-initialization-in-c

Answer (score 5):

> > How do we know pointers are not initialized to NULL by default?

Because we know that the standard says that default initialised pointer has an indeterminate value if it has automatic or dynamic storage. Quote from the standard (draft):

> [dcl.init] If no initializer is specified for an object, the object is default-initialized. When storage for an object
> with automatic or dynamic storage duration is obtained, the object has an **indeterminate value**, and if
> no initialization is performed for the object, that object retains an indeterminate value until that value
> is replaced. ...

And further:

> [dcl.init] To default-initialize an object of type T means:
>
> — If T is a (possibly cv-qualified) class type [pointer isn't a class, so we don't care]
>
> — If T is an array type [pointer isn't an array, so we don't care]
>
> — Otherwise, **no initialization is performed.**

---

> > I have declared a char (and also int) pointer without initializing it , and I got null pointers.

Reading an indeterminate value has undefined behaviour. Quote from the standard (draft):

> [dcl.init] ... If an indeterminate value is produced by an evaluation, the **behavior is undefined** except in the
> following cases: [cases which don't apply here]

Comment: @SergeyA I added qualification.

Comment: Much better now. :)

Comment: @user463035818 see the exact quotes

Comment: thanks, already the second time today I learn something important from you :). So compilers are a bit sloppy when complaining about a variable being used unitialized, because default-initialization is also a form of initialization, no?

Comment: @user463035818 I suppose it can still be uninitialised, considering "default initialisation" of the variable doesn't initialise it :) It can be a bit confusing.

Comment: well thats why I asked. I was afraid there is a distinction between not initialized and default initialized with an indeterminate value. Anyhow, I will have to do some reading...

Answer (score 1):

The question you linked to handles variables with local storage duration exclusively, so I assume you refer to these as well.

Such variables are not initialised if you don't do so yourself, so they get the value of whatever was written in their memory location before (standard wording: their value is 'indeterminate') – nothing speaks against, though, that this memory already *is* zero – by pure accident!

You can try the following:

```
void test()
{
    int* p; // uninitialized
    std::cout << p << std::endl; // undefined behaviour!!!
    // (that's what you most likely did already...)

    // now something new: change the memory...
    p = reinterpret_cast<int*>(static_cast<uintptr_t(0xaddadaad));
}

int main()
{
    test();

    // again something new: call it a SECOND time:
    test();
}
```

As this is undefined behaviour there are no guarantees at all that you will get any meaningful output – chances are, though that the memory of first function call is reused in second one and you *might* get output ressembling to the following:

```
00000000
addadaad
```

So even if there just *happened* to be  all zero memory at programme start, it might differ from that at some later point while your programme is running...

Comment: This is a good point. Because of  OS security reasons memory given to your application could be initially filled with 0. However that does not mean that you should make use of this. This answer shows how making use of this undefined behavior can and will cause unexpected results.